# kotlin-android-extensions stop working if lifecycle-extensions is included in gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-android-extensions, android-components

After adding the Android lifecycle component to my project with the following line: `implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion")`
in my app's build.gradle.kts file all the import `kotlinx.android.synthetic` stop working, lifecycleVersion is defined as "2.0.0"

It gives me the following error in the places where I use the imported views. And the imports are marked as unused by the IDE

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:

I tried moving the source code from the main/java folder to a main/kotlin one after searching for a solution online but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was that since the navigation dependencies must be (for now) in the `android.arch` distribution adding `androidx` dependencies messed with the project.
The problem have been solved by replacing the previous conflicting dependency to:

```
implementation("android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1")
```

It is curious that the only conflicting dependency was that one and not the others. But after changing all the dependencies to the `android.arch` distribution the problem have been solved.